# hear sb do / hear sb doing, what's the difference

Tags: meaning

> I heard them sing.
>
> I heard them singing.

What's the different meaning of these two sentences?

Comment: If by *sb* you mean *somebody*, please use the complete word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinitive 'sing' means the entire process of singing, whereas the V-ing 'singing' means only part of the process of singing.

If they sang for five minutes, you heard for five minutes in the first sentence, whereas you heard for less than five minutes in the second.

Comment: Yes - 'I heard them sing' suggests that you attended a performance; 'I heard them singing' that you just happened to come within earshot of the sound.